# JIRA access public issues

Tags: java, authentication, jira, public

How should I access public issues since "401 Unauthorized" exception occurs when I access it through Java.

Few public issues are:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search
- https://issues.sonatype.org/rest/api/2/search
- https://jira.springsource.org/rest/api/2/search
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search
- http://jira.codehaus.org/rest/api/2/search

Code:

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
URI jiraServerUri = new URI("https://issues.sonatype.org/rest/api/2/search");
JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, username, password);
```